# Time Complexity on Linux Shell

Tags: linux, shell, time, time-complexity

I created this simple algorithm, for studying it's complexity.  [Algorithm 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tHxC.png)

I studied its complexity, O(n^3), and tried using the "time" command on the Linux Shell. [Timing execution Algorithm 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dnzp.png)

So I decided to increase the complexity, about O(n^5). [Algorithm 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVaTI.png)

But when I use the Time command, the times don't increase as I thought. [Timing execution Algorithm 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYhX.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post the text directly. How did you compile the sources? Any optimizations involved?

Comment: Is this a shell question, or rather a C++ question? The shell is just used to measure the time.

Comment: To compile I've done " g++ -o exec File.cpp " and with " time ./exec " I testing my code.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I just wanted to know why if I increase the complexity when I test my code the complexity decrease.

Comment: A question needs to have enough details to be answerable even if the links fail to be on-topic; content only behind links does not count towards satisfying [mre] requirements, to help ensure that our knowledge base will remain useful even after off-site links have broken.

Comment: Also, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for the tips, I'm new to the platform and tried to be brief, but I should have been more thorough

Answer (score 0):

I think the time is not increasing because of the values of n.
Basically when n is high, the variable named 'a' inside the 'f' function can't hold such a high number .
using a debugger and n=1000000000, I got a random number as a result (-1486618624) because the [maximum number that a int can hold in c++ is 2147483647](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/int_max-int_min-cc-applications/#:%7E:text=Value%20of%20INT_MAX%20is%20%2B2147483647.), maybe this is why you'r not seeing any changes,you can try and use other types like long long that will serve you better in this case ( i wanted to comment this answer but i don't have enough reputation x) )